# Are these random UID applications spywares?

Tags: applications, mobile-data, malware, unknown-sources

It's been a year since I am ignoring all these Applications using my data and battery. At first, I thought they could be apps that I uninstalled a while ago. But, no, every third day they were showing up in logs with the exact same UID, and if I restricted their data, then the next day they still showed up with another UID but used the same data and battery. No doubt these are spyware.

[image] [image]

If they're, then how should I get rid of these without a factory reset?

Comment: That those processes with data usage change their uid is indeed strange. But if those processes manage to re-install themselves to get a new uid there might be more than those two malicious processes. In the end I don't think you will be able to get rid of those processes without a factory reset.

Comment: Which Android version and Android device are you using? Use this [app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager/) to sort installed apps based on "Last Update". Share the screenshots with us.